# Ensuring date/times are correct globally PHP 5.3/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have spent the last two days reading up on this and ultimately have ended up just as confused as when I started.  I know the question has been asked many times before but I seem to be getting nowhere fast.

The problem is there seems to be such a wide variety of recommendations and differing advice given all over the web, including here on Stackoverflow.

So, I was hoping someone could set me straight once and for all.

Given that I have full control over both the server and the code, what is the best method to ensure that when a user performs a certain action the correct date/time is stored in the database and that any users from other timezones also get the correct time returned, relative to their timezone.

i.e.  User A in France posts a comment, he sees the correct time returned when viewing that comment.  User B in America view user A's comment and sees the time it was posted corrected to his timezone.

I need to know the best method to store the date/time in mysql and the best method to retrieve this date and display it correctly for any given client wherever they are in the world.

I am using PHP 5.3 and mySQL 5.5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Store the data in a GMT (no offset) format or a unix timestamp and apply the users local timezone when displaying that information to them.

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh, I understand the concept but seem to be getting confused with all the different date formats in mySQL along with the varying date/datetime functions in PHP 5.3.  If you could elaborate your commnt into an answer including the best formats/functions to user for each I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the date in UTC:

```
$utctime = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', date('U')); // get timestamp and convert it to UTC
```

and display to user with his offset, you can ask him what timezone he has or you can try to get it, using AJAX or based on his IP.

Let's say his timezone is +7 hours:

```
$usertime = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($utctime)+(7*60*60));
```

you can store as timestamp: `$utctime = gmdate('U', date('U'));`

Comment: Thanks Mihai, how would I get the clients timezone in php in order to display the time correctly? Also what format in mySQL would be best too save this data?

Comment: @gordyr That's the magic question. You can do all sorts of things (IP ranges, javascript to get local system times etc) but the safest is to simply *ask* them when they make an account to pick their offset.

Comment: You can store it as timestamp as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Ahh I see thanks for the edit.  The last line makes sense to me and I think I have grasped the concept now.  The only problem I see with this method is if someone travels from one country to the next and accesses their account abroad, their times will not be in sync.  I guess for that I would have to add javascript into the stack.  Regardless, you have answered my question. Thank you.